# Error de-serializing Set in JSON

Tags: java, json, serialization, spring-boot

I have a use case where I have to use polymorphism for objects as these are the response from third party server.
This is one of my response class:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(
        use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS,
        include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY,
        defaultImpl = RiderUpdate.class,
        property = "@class")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class RiderUpdate implements Serializable {

    @JsonProperty("status")
    private RiderStatus riderStatus;
    private Location location;
    @JsonProperty("orderIds")
    private Set<Long> orderIds;

    @JsonProperty("createdAt")
    private DateTime updatedAt;
    @JsonProperty("trackedObjectId")
    private String riderId;
```

This is my Object mapper config

```
@Bean
    public ObjectMapper buildMapper() {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.registerModule(new JodaModule()).setDateFormat(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"));
        mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
        mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
        mapper.registerSubtypes(RiderUpdate.class, RiderStatus.class, Location.class);
        mapper.enableDefaultTyping(ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.NON_FINAL, JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY);
        return mapper;
    }
```

My mapper functions which I am using to serialize:

```
@Component
public class JsonUtils {

    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(JsonUtils.class);


    public String serializeObject(Object object) throws IOException {
        return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(object);
    }

    public <T> T readObject(String source, Class<T> objectClass) {
        T result = null;
        try {
            result = objectMapper.readValue(source, objectClass);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

I am trying to parse the following string :

```
{\"orderIds\":[3961393],\"location\": {\"latitude\":28 , \"longitude\":77},\"createdAt\":\"2017-02-22T16:26:29.982+05:30\",\"trackedObjectId\":\"1\"}
```

I am getting JSON errors while parsing.:

```
Unexpected token (VALUE_NUMBER_INT), expected VALUE_STRING: need JSON String that contains type id (for subtype of java.util.Set)
```

Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need change `riderId` type from `String` to `int` or `long`

```
private int riderId;
```

Number to String implicit conversion is not possible. That's why you are getting error. Though `trackedObjectId` value seems to have a number in between the double quotes, after parsing by json engine it will be converted to number. So, practically your code is trying to assign a number to String. As this is not possible you are getting exception.

Comment: But the exception is saying something related to set. I changed the set to an array and it starts working. I didn't touch riderId though. But I want to use it as a set.